# SQL Server INNER JOIN vs WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Which following solution is better.

```
Declare @ID as int = 1234

Select MAX(q2.ID)
FROM (SELECT col1,col2 FROM table Where ID=@ID) q1 
     INNER JOIN table q2 on q1.col1 = q2.col1 and q1.col2=q2.col2
WHERE q2.ID < q1.ID
```

VS

```
Declare @col1Val varchar(50)
Declare @col2Val varchar(50)

Select @col1Val=col1, @col2Val=col2 FROM table where ID=@ID

SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table 
WHERE ID < @ID AND col1 = @col1Val and col2 = @col2Val
```

- What's the performance differences on these 2 option?
- Why doesn't option 1 execution plan report missing index ? Option 2
  report index missing for col1, col2 ?
- Is there a better option 3 ?

Comment: Your first SQL statement is invalid, as derived table`q1` has no column `ID`.

Comment: @TT. It's a self join

Comment: Not the way it is written. You define a derived table in the from clause based on a select in `table` and named it `q1`. You then proceed to join this derived table with table `q2`. Since you didn't select the `ID` column in derived table `q1`, the join is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query execution plans may give you an idea of which one is performing better than the other. It appears you have already reviewed that, which is awesome.

In case of the 2nd query, I recommend trying to create an index on ID, col1 and col2 on q2 table and then reviewing whether execution plans are showing improvements on the 2nd query in particular. I expect that the queries will perform equally well then. This index is a covering index since all you need from

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table 
WHERE ID < @ID AND col1 = @col1Val and col2 = @col2Val
```

will be found from the index itself.

I suspect that your first query is using col1 and col2 index (I believe it's a composite index) for grouping and ID (I believe it's a primary key) for the where clause. The 2nd query is probably trying to use the best index that can satisfy the where clause and using just the primary key (if clustered, it will show up as clustered index in your execution plan).

There's another option you could try. I have not tested this query against a dummy table, so you may have to tweak it slightly

```
select top 1 q2.id
from table q2
where exists (
  select 1
  from table q1
  where q1.id=@id
    and q1.col1 = q2.col1
    and q1.col2 = q2.col2
    and q1.id > q2.id
)
order by q2.id desc
```

OR

```
select max(q2.id)
from table q2
where exists (
  select 1
  from table q1
  where q1.id=@id
    and q1.col1 = q2.col1
    and q1.col2 = q2.col2
    and q1.id > q2.id
)
```

Add an index on q1 and q2 on id, col1 and col2 if they are different tables.

You could also remove the `where` clause from your first query and try:

```
Select MAX(q2.ID)
FROM (SELECT col1,col2 FROM table Where ID=@ID) q1 
INNER JOIN table q2 on 
  q1.col1 = q2.col1 
  and q1.col2=q2.col2
  and q2.ID < q1.ID
```

Give it a shot. If you have a sample table structure and data, feel free to use http://sqlfiddle.com to create an example to get better feedback.

Comment: you are saying a join will not leverage index? so it will do a full loop anyway? by "composite index" , what do you mean. If this is the case, does it mean that the second query will always better than the first one when the index in place?

Comment: Hi @LeY, many questions - (1) joins will leverage index if present and stats are good (2) db tries to avoid full loops (3) composite index means index with more than 1 columns. (4) estimation plan and running the query with actual plan will give you an idea of which one runs faster. I cannot say definitively which query is going to be faster. I believe they will both work reasonably fast with the right indexes